# Edit content on click of pencil icon

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular10

I am working on angular application. I have a title in my page and code is as follows

```
<div>my Title
   <fa name="pencil"></fa>
 </div>
```

so title will be shown with pencil icon in near/parallel to it. I don't want to show it as text field but when user clicks pencil icon I want to allow user to enter title. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
<div (click)="onEdit()"><fa name="pencil"></fa></div>
```

And your ts file

```
onEdit() {
    // JS Edit Code
}
```

Comment: how it be updated on screen when mouse is clicked outside or enter is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Zaib, Angular make a relation between variables in .ts and the .html. So the "easy way" is has a div and an input. a variable makes that you show one or another

```
editing:boolean=false;  //<--this is your variable in .ts
title:string="my Title"; //<--another variable 


<span *ngIf="!editing">{{title}}</span>
<input *ngIf="editing" [(ngModel)]="title" (blur)="editing=false">
<span (click)="editing=true"><fa name="pencil"></fa></span>
```

See how you only show "{{title}}" if the variable "editing" is false, and only show the input if the variable "editing" is true.

When you "click" the "pencil", you put the variable editing to true, when you lost focus from the input you put the variable editing to false

Well, you now know he basic. But we are improve the code. It's good that if you make the (click) the focus goes to the input. So we are going to take another aproach: we are going to use [style.display] to show or not the "span" and the "input"

```
<span [style.display]="editing?'none':null">{{title}}</span>
<input #inputId [style.display]="!editing?'none':null" 
        [(ngModel)]="title" (blur)="editing=false">
<span (click)="edit(inputId)"><fa name="pencil"></fa></span>
```

And create a function

```
edit(element:any){
     this.editing=true;
     setTimeout(()=>{
       element.focus()
     })
}
```

See how we can write functions that response to event in the .html -Typicals events, (click), (input), (blur)....

Furthermore, to make reference to a variable in the .ts inside a function we use `this.`+name of the variable.

The strange "#inputId" is called template reference variable and allow us to make reference to the html element

Well there're much more, take a look to the [officials docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)